# Debian - GIT upgrade from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: linux, git, debian

A simple question,

I want to upgrade an existing GIT installation onto my VPS server. The thing is that, when I'm writting into the command line:

```
apt-get install git-core
```

I can get only **1.5.6.5** version which is depricated. How to upgrade / reinstall GIT to get 1.7.3 or newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a very old version of Debian (version **5**). It is not even supported, so maybe consider upgrading it. Otherwise, you may get away with just building a later git version yourself.